# Helper length 0 in constructor

Tags: angular-meteor

I am trying to access the items from my helper within the constructor however it returns 0. If I display the length in a view it shows the correct amount.

Is there a correct way to do this?

```
this.helpers({
        bases() {
            return Bases.find({}, {sort:{base:1}});
        }
    });

    console.log("length: " + this.bases.length); // = 0 should be 16
    console.log("reactivly " + this.getReactively('bases').length ); // = 0 should be 16
```

Thanks for your help